# How can my cpu frequency be above maximum MHz value in lscpu?

Tags: linux, cpu, node.js, cpu-frequency, lscpu

How can it be, that my current cpu frequency (*CPU MHz)* for my [Intel Core2 Duo T9400M](http://www.cpu-world.com/CPUs/Core_2/Intel-Core%202%20Duo%20Mobile%20T9400%20AW80576GH0616M%20(BX80576T9400).html) is above *max MHz* while being on high load?

```
➜ lscpu
[...]
Model name:          Intel(R) Core(TM)2 Duo CPU     T9400M  @ 2.53GHz
Stepping:            10
CPU MHz:             2606.581
CPU max MHz:         2534.0000
CPU min MHz:         800.0000
[...]
```

This isn't limited to lscpu: I get similar values out of */proc/cpuinfo*:

```
➜ bat /proc/cpuinfo
[...]
model name  : Intel(R) Core(TM)2 Duo CPU     T9400  @ 2.53GHz
cpu MHz     : 2635.237
[...]
```

I found this out while looking over the Node.js documentation and finding, that the current speed value of [os.cpus()](https://nodejs.org/api/os.html#os_os_cpus) - even in the example of the documentation - is above the maximum CPU speed according to the model:

```
[
  {
    model: 'Intel(R) Core(TM) i7 CPU         860  @ 2.80GHz',
    speed: 2926,
[...]
```

Comment: ``bat`` = ``cat``?

Comment: Yes, bat is "a cat clone with wings." https://github.com/sharkdp/bat

Comment: `less` is `more`, and `bat` is `cat`. This is madness!    :-)    ⁠

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In both cases, your CPU can run slightly faster than its specified frequency, typically when one of its cores is running a CPU-intensive process, and the others aren’t. On your Core 2 Mobile system, this was provided by [Intel Dynamic Acceleration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_Dynamic_Acceleration); on the Core i7, by [Turbo Boost](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_Turbo_Boost).

The exact details vary from one processor to another. Earlier CPUs could only boost one core, but nowadays multiple cores can be boosted. The CPU ensures it stays within a certain power and thermal envelope.